# Git clone deleted all files in directory

Tags: git, github

This is partly me being silly, and stupid. I thought it was worth seeing if anyone had any idea how I can get my stuff back.

I enabled 2FA on my github, and created an empty repo online. I cloned it in using git bash. When I saw the directory was in, I cut and pasted my code into that directory. I then saw it hadn't cloned the .gitignore. I checked bash, and it required me to put in my username and password. I did, but it came up with an error, because of the 2FA. It then deleted the entire directory, along with the rest of my code in it.

I couldn't recover it using git lost-found, nor using EaseUS or Recuva. Any ideas?

Comment: If you are using MacOS is not an error you have to get the security key and pass it as password in the shell window. For you to recover you code if you deleted the .git file well at that point don't know if there is a coming back

Comment: Had you committed your changes after you added the code in directory? Also clonning the directory won't switch you to that directory unless you explicitly cd to it

Comment: I'm using windows. The .git file got cloned, and subsequently deleted when the credentials were wrong.

Comment: No. This happened all during the clone itself. It hadn't finished cloning properly, and seemed to have "rolled" back by deleting the directory, including the code I pasted in.

Comment: Where exactly you pasted code inside repository you cloned?

Comment: It wasn't code, it was files. I had a project that I wanted to put on github. I cut + pasted all my files whilst cloning.

Answer (score 0):

If you cut your files, then if you're lucky they may still be in your clipboard.  Try repeating the 'paste' command in a new empty folder.

Barring that, 'undo' may come through for you.  Try pressing ctrl-z in the file browser, in the directory you cut your code from.

Comment: I doubt the clipboard holds the *contents* of the files.

Comment: I tried both at the time. Neither worked, unfortunately.